# How to add questions into a pyqt thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

EDIT: I have attempted to add a slot to use a signal so the question box is handled by the main thread and not the worker, but it does not open the question box it just finishes the thread. I am also unsure of how to make the worker wait for the result of the question and how to return to the worker once I know what the user wants to do.

The code I have is used to test some boards and based on what happens the thread should either continue on to the next test if there was a pass or ask the user a question if there was a failure. The problem is when there is a failure the question box appears but the thread in the background continues, I don't want that to happen as the result of subsequent tests rely on the answers from the tests before.

Below is a example of what I do not want to happen.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSlot

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    question = pyqtSignal()

class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            self.signals.progress.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btnStartTest = QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.labelOne = QLabel("Test one")
        self.labelTwo = QLabel("Test two")

        layout.addWidget(self.btnStartTest)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelOne)
        layout.addWidget(self.labelTwo)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.btnStartTest.clicked.connect(self.runTestsThread)

        self.show()

    def runTestsThread(self):

        # Pass the function to execute
        worker = Worker(self.execute_this_fn)
        worker.signals.question.connect(self.question_asked)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)

        # Execute
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def execute_this_fn(self):

        resultOne = "FAIL"
        resultTwo = "PASS"

        if resultOne == "PASS":
            self.labelOne.setStyleSheet("background-color: LightGreen")
        else:
            self.labelOne.setStyleSheet("background-color: Red")
            self.question.emit()
            

        if resultTwo == "PASS":
            self.labelTwo.setStyleSheet("background-color: LightGreen")
        else:
            self.labelTwo.setStyleSheet("background-color: Red")
            self.question.emit()

    def thread_complete(self):
        print("thread complete")

    def question_asked(self):
        QMessageBox.question(self, "Message Box!!", "Do you want to continue or quit")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main = MainWindow()
    Main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried using a signal to finish the thread if there is a failure, then ask the question but this did not work. I was unsure of how to then start another thread based on the answer to the question.

Any help on how to structure this would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: The worker tries to perform GUI operations outside the main thread, which is not supported by Qt. But in any case, there is no obvious reason for using multi-threading in your example. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it not being supported by Qt? I thought threading was supported as I have managed to create and run a thread as shown above. The reason for my code to run as a thread is that I have things going on in the test that need to be run in the background (serial reads, logging, SQL write/reads etc) that need to run without looking up the main thread and causing the main GUI to go unresponsive. I have not included all this to keep the sample code as small as possible as I thought this was required and welcomed when asking a question on stack overflow?

Comment: Qt does not support ***GUI operations*** of any kind outside the main thread. In general, widgets aren't *thread-safe*, so you should never attempt to directly create or update them inside worker threads (see: [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)). Instead, use custom signals to send notifications to the main thread, and perform all the GUI-specific operations there.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense and I did kind of know that. I am still struggling, I have edited the code to show how I think to use a slot to then ask the question, but it does not seem to open the question box. How do I get the thread to wait while the question is waiting for the result, and how to return that result to the thread so if the user wants to continue it will continue and if they want to quit it will finish?

Comment: The code makes very little sense, since you're still trying to perform GUI operations in different threads. All user interaction via widgets **must** occur within the main thread. Communication between threads should be done via signals and slots. However, I fail to see (despite your comments above) why you really need to use multi-threading at all. At the moment, it seems like a case of premature optimisation (although, without seeing realistic example code, it's hard to be sure).